# How to add hyperlink for Label in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

```
FormattedString  t = new FormattedString();
t.Spans.Add(new Span() { Text = "About my Self\n\n" });
t.Spans.Add(new Span() { Text = "1. My website\n\n" }); 
t.Spans.Add(new Span() { Text = "2. My  Linkedin profile\n\n" }); 
t.Spans.Add(new Span() { Text = "3. Twitter\n\n" });
```

I have a Text like above, I am able to set hyperlink [whole text](https://www.codementor.io/softsan/xamarin-forms-hyperlink-label-6tt3225fk) but I want to set a hyperlink for **website** and **Linkedin** words with some URL.

How can I set hyperlink for particular word in Paragraph for Label

Please help me on that.Thanks!!

Comment: Create multiple labels

Comment: As SushiHangover mentioned create multiple label controls and add TapGesture to them, something like this:

Label label = new Label() {
    Text = "Some text/url"
};
label.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer((view) => OnLabelClicked()));

after that create OnLabelClicked method and handle opening url in browser etc.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that, your best choice is to create multiple labels or add a gesture recognizer for the whole text, wich would be a better idea since clicking on a small word is difficult on certain devices and the gesture recognizers on Xamarin are not the best ones around.

Answer (score 1):

This might help for you: [AwesomeHyperLinkLabel](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2016/03/10/so-i-created-this-awesomehyperlinklabel-custom-renderer-control-one-day-for-xamarin-forms/) . I myself looking way to implement this and will start with this link, but I want to improve it a bit and replace links text with friendly text so instead direct link to page it would say "my page"